# Hide fields by default

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, jquery

i use this jQuery code to hide all fields below, how I can to to be hidden by default on page load?

```
var showRadio = jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(1)').find('input');
var hideRadio = jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(2)').find('input');

hideRadio.click(function() {
  jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').hide();
  jQuery(this).parents('dd').show();
  jQuery(this).parents('dd').prevAll('dt:first').show();
})
showRadio.click(function() {
  jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').show();
})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var showRadio = jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(2)').find('input');
var hideRadio = jQuery('.product-options .display ul li:nth-child(1)').find('input');
if(hideRadio){
    jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').hide();
    hideRadio.parents('dd').show();
    hideRadio.parents('dd').prevAll('dt:first').show();
}

hideRadio.click(function() {
  jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').hide();
  jQuery(this).parents('dd').show();
  jQuery(this).parents('dd').prevAll('dt:first').show();
})
showRadio.click(function() {
  jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').show();
})
});
```

Answer (score 2):

by default  you can use css  property `display:none` to hide those fields.

else you put this function outside function

`jQuery('.product-options dd, .product-options dt').hide();` will do work for you but i recommended the first one.